# How to get values from property-file into Map using Spring framework?

Tags: spring

For now I could inject values from property-files:

```
@Value("${aaa.prop}")
public String someProp;
```

But I want something more...

For example I have some property file:

```
aaa.props=p1,p2,p3
aaa.props.p1=qwe
aaa.props.p2=asd
aaa.props.p3=zxc
```

I know for sure, that it contains property `aaa.props`, and know nothing about other properties. And I want to get this properties in to map using code like this:

```
@Value ("${aaa.props}") 
public Map<String, String> someProps;
```

Resulting someProps: `{p1=qwe,p2=asd,p3=zxc}`

Comment: You may find answers to this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file . Inject properties object as resource, parse list one and build your map accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Well I built a generic approach for you: a factory bean that creates a map by filtering another map (properties are a kind of map, after all).

Here's the factory bean:

```
public class FilteredMapFactoryBean<V> extends
    AbstractFactoryBean<Map<String, V>>{

    private Map<String, V> input;

    /**
     * Set the input map.
     */
    public void setInput(final Map<String, V> input){
        this.input = input;
    }

    /**
     * Set the string by which key prefixes will be filtered.
     */
    public void setKeyFilterPrefix(final String keyFilterPrefix){
        this.entryFilter = new EntryFilter<String, V>(){

            @Override
            public boolean accept(final Entry<String, V> entry){
                return entry.getKey().startsWith(keyFilterPrefix);
            }
        };
    }

    public static interface EntryFilter<EK, EV> {

        boolean accept(Map.Entry<EK, EV> entry);
    }

    /**
     * If a prefix is not enough, you can supply a custom filter.
     */
    public void setEntryFilter(final EntryFilter<String, V> entryFilter){
        this.entryFilter = entryFilter;
    }

    private EntryFilter<String, V> entryFilter;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType(){
        return Map.class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected Map<String, V> createInstance() throws Exception{
        final Map<String, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, V>();
        for(final Entry<String, V> entry : this.input.entrySet()){
            if(this.entryFilter == null || this.entryFilter.accept(entry)){
                map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

Here is a spring bean definition file with some sample usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- use System.getProperties() as input -->
    <bean class="spring.test.FilteredMapFactoryBean" id="javaMap">
        <property name="keyFilterPrefix" value="java." />
        <property name="input" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getProperties()}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- use custom properties as input -->
    <bean class="spring.test.FilteredMapFactoryBean" id="customMap">
        <property name="keyFilterPrefix" value="hello" />
        <property name="input">
            <props>
                <prop key="hello">Is it me you're looking for?</prop>
                <prop key="hello.again">Just called to say: hello.</prop>
                <prop key="hello.goodby">You say goodbye and I say hello</prop>
                <prop key="goodbye.blue.sky">Did-did-did-did-you hear the falling bombs?</prop>
                <prop key="goodbye.ruby.tuesday">Who could hang a name on you?</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And here is a test class:

```
public class Tester{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(final String[] args){
        final ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/test/mapFactorybean.xml");

        final Map<String, String> javaMap =
            (Map<String, String>) context.getBean("javaMap");
        print("java.", javaMap);
        final Map<String, String> customMap =
            (Map<String, String>) context.getBean("customMap");
        print("hello.", customMap);

    }

    private static void print(final String prefix, final Map<String, String> map){
        System.out.println("Map of items starting with " + prefix);
        for(final Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("\t" + entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

The output is as expected:

```
Map of items starting with java.
    java.runtime.name:Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.vm.version:14.2-b01
    java.vm.vendor:Sun Microsystems Inc.
    java.vendor.url:http://java.sun.com/
    java.vm.name:Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
    java.vm.specification.name:Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.runtime.version:1.6.0_16-b01
    java.awt.graphicsenv:sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
        [... etc]

Map of items starting with hello.
    hello.goodby:You say goodbye and I say hello
    hello:Is it me you're looking for?
    hello.again:Just called to say: hello.
```

Comment: `AbstractFactoryBean` is singleton by default. Wouldn't it be a problem to use this bean several times (with different properties) in a context?

Comment: @naXa this answer is 4 years old. these days FactoryBeans are kinda deprecated. I'd go with \@Configuration classes instead

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't, directly. But you can

- implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) and set the `ApplicationContext` as a field in your bean.
- in a `@PostConstruct` method call `context.getBean("${aaa.props}")`
- parse the result manually and set it to the desired fields

Comment: Is there a way to get all properties to to find ones I need?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `@Value`.

Properties file:

```
aaa.props={p1:'qwe',p2:'asd',p3:'zxc'}
```

Java code:

```
@Value("#{${aaa.props}}")
private Map<String,String> someProps;
```

Comment: This is what should get upvoted and accepted as the answer. Additionally, those who use Spring XML based configuration, could simply inject this using properties such like `p:someProps="#{${aaa.props}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:
Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add the import.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
```

...

```
@Resource (name="propertiesMapName") 
public Properties someProps;
```

In your spring xml application context:

```
<util:properties id="propertiesMapName" location="classpath:yourFile.properties"/>
```

You will need this namespace

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
```

Comment: can i know why i have -1 in the solution? This works and i think is a pretty clean way, i would like to understand what is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The solution it's well defined on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```