# Spring : message.properties file not working

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation

In my validation process of application, i used `message.properties` file to show *custom message*. But it is not working and shows the following error in App Engine server log as

> **org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag: No message found under code 'notmatch.password' for locale
>   'en_US'. org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No
>   message found under code 'notmatch.password' for locale 'en_US'.**

My code for validation is :

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password",
            "required.password", "Field name is required.");

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "confirmPassword",
            "required.confirmPassword", "Field name is required.");

    NewUser cust = (NewUser) target;

    if (!(cust.getPassword().equals(cust.getConfirmPassword()))) {
        errors.rejectValue("password", "notmatch.password");
    }

}
```

My configuration xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename"
            value="/WEB-INF/resources/message_en_US.properties" />
    </beans:bean>



        <beans:bean name="/register" class="com.my.registration.NewUserRegistration">
        <beans:property name="validator">
            <beans:bean class="com.my.validation.UserValidator" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="formView" value="newuser"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="successView" value="home"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

[image: My project file structure is given in the image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have `notmatch.password` key in `message_en_US.properties` file like

```
notmatch.password = Inccorect password
```

and change the basename to

```
<beans:property name="basename"
            value="/WEB-INF/resources/message" />
```

For more information check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/).

Answer (score 1):

Configure PropertyPlaceholder in your context:

```
<context:property-placeholder locations="classpath*:my.properties"/>
```

For more details check this post also.

[How to read values from properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file)