# Invalid target for Validator - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm having problems with validating in Spring. I'm getting the following error after opening the form:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [com.example.validator.UserValidator@6ac0a8f4]: com.example.web.forms.UserDTO@4d3b2379
```

My Validator for the time being, wanted to check if anything works first:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    ServiceUser serviceUser;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) target;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "NotEmpty.userForm.name");

    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserValidator userValidator;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true, 10);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
        binder.setValidator(userValidator);
//        binder.addValidators(userValidator);
    }

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    protected ServiceUserImpl service;


    @RequestMapping("/lista")
    public String showIndex(Model model) {
        User contest = new User();
        model.addAttribute("element", contest);
        model.addAttribute("collection", service.findAll());
        return "lista";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/dodaj")
    public String showFormPublication(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("userDto") @Valid UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult result) {
        if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post") && !result.hasErrors()) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "forms/contest";
            } else {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(userDTO.getId());
                user.setName(userDTO.getName());
                user.setSurname(userDTO.getSurname());
                user.setDateOfBirth(userDTO.getDateOfBirth());
                user.setIndexNumber(userDTO.getIndexNumber());
                user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
                service.save(user);

                return "redirect:/lista";
            }
        }
        return "dodaj";
    }
}
```

Form in .jsp:

```
<form:form action="dodaj" method="POST" modelAttribute="userDto">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Imię</th>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="text" path="name" />
                    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors path="name" /></c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nazwisko</th>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="text" path="surname" />
                    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors path="surname" /></c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>DataUrodzenia</th>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="date" path="dateOfBirth" />
                    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors path="dateOfBirth" /></c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>NumerIndeksu</th>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="number" path="indexNumber" />
                    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors path="indexNumber" /></c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="text" path="email" />
                    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors path="email" /></c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Dodaj!" /></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

I tried adding ("userDto") next to @InitBinder, it didn't help unfortunately. Haven't found much more in terms of applicable solutions. If there's anything else I should post here let me know. I can also provide a link to repository should anyone be eager enough to try to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the `supports` method in `UserValidator` to `UserDTO` class:

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
     return UserDTO.class.equals(clazz);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that and changing the User in validate method to UserDTO helped. Hovewer now I have another error after trying to submit invalid form - org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'NotEmpty.userForm.name.userDTO.name' for locale 'pl_PL'. How to get rid of that or add a localised message?

Comment: It's looking for the text to show for that error, using key `NotEmpty.userForm.name.userDTO.name`. Do you have that in a messages.properties file? Refer to similar answers like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257303/4505142

Comment: I had that in validation.properties file. Tried renaming to messages.properties just to be sure, but realised that I do not have the messages configured anywhere so I'm currently working on that.

Comment: All I managed to do was to enable the annotations with a huge workaround instead of just adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. What I'm getting right now is "may not be empty" as I have the `@NotEmpty` annotation, and the result should be different since in the messages.properties I have `NotEmpty.userForm.name.userDTO.name = Name is required!` EDIT - I just forgot to uncomment `binder.setValidator(userValidator);`, everything works, thank you very much for help.