# Can @PropertySources be chosen by Spring profile?

Tags: spring

I have a Spring 3.1 `@Configuration` that needs a property `foo` to build a bean. The property is  defined in `defaults.properties` but may be overridden by the property in `overrides.properties` if the application has an active `override` Spring profile.

Without the override, the code would look like this, and work...

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:defaults.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Bean bean() {
        ...
        // this.environment.getRequiredProperty("foo");
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like a `@PropertySource` for `classpath:overrides.properties` contingent on `@Profile("overrides")`. Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved? Some options I've considered are a duplicate `@Configuration`, but that would violate DRY, or programmatic manipulation of the `ConfigurableEnvironment`, but I'm not sure where the `environment.getPropertySources.addFirst()` call would go.

Placing the following in an XML configuration works if I inject the property directly with `@Value`, but not when I use `Environment` and the `getRequiredProperty()` method.

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath:defaults.properties"/>

<beans profile="overrides">
    <context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" order="0"
                                  location="classpath:overrides.properties"/>
</beans>
```

**Update**

If you're trying to do this now, check out Spring Boot's [YAML support](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html), particularly the 'Using YAML instead of Properties' section. The profile support there would make this question moot, but there isn't `@PropertySource` support yet.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add the overriding `@PropertySource` in a static inner class. Unfortunately, you must specify all property sources together which means creating a "default" profile as the alternative to "override".

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration
{
    @Configuration
    @Profile("default")
    @PropertySource("classpath:defaults.properties")
    static class Defaults
    { }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("override")
    @PropertySource({"classpath:defaults.properties", "classpath:overrides.properties"})
    static class Overrides
    {
        // nothing needed here if you are only overriding property values
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Bean bean() {
        ...
        // this.environment.getRequiredProperty("foo");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't understand why this answer got so many upvotes. Hard-coding the profile names is against the point of profiles. Isn't there a similar way that let's you specify the profile through the 'spring.profiles.active' parameter?

Comment: Today you coul use profile specific property files. I do not know if that has already been possible when this answer has been written (look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)).

Comment: @Fencer That is available only if you are using Spring Boot.

Comment: @NimaAJ That may be true, but since jjoller was referring to 'spring.profiles.active' my hint might be a valuable Information for those stumbling over his question. Probably the use of 'spring.profiles.active' implicates the use of Spring Boot or the possibility of using profile specific property files. I should have added '@jjoller' though.

Comment: @jjoller Check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57756856/425238

Comment: @jjoller if hard-coding like this were against the point of profiles, there would be no point in the @Profile() annotation existing. It exists for a good reason: to allow code to be activated by profiles. I think this is a good use. (Although I'm using Spille's approach below)

Comment: Update: actually I like this approach better than Spille's and whitebrows, because using the ${spring.profiles.active} variable fails if you have multiple active profles. This @Profile approach, on the other hand, enables very flexible logic (documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

Answer (score 25):

I suggest, defining two files, where the second is optional with the profile as suffix:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:/myconfig.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/myconfig-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class MyConfigurationFile {

    @Value("${my.prop1}")
    private String prop1;

    @Value("${my.prop2}")
    private String prop2;

}
```

Comment: For me this part is doing the magic: `${spring.profiles.active}`, now I can have two files: `config-dev.properties` and `config-prod.properties` and the java class have the next line `@PropertySource("classpath:config-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")`

Comment: This fails if you have multiple profiles (E.g. I had active profiles = "dev,mock"

Comment: im lucky to find this answer. simple and straightforward. you saved me.

Comment: You can use `${spring.active.profiles}` to fix for multiple profiles

Comment: `${spring.active.profiles}` doesn't exist, and i don't see how it would solve for multiple profiles anyway

Answer (score 10):

You can do:

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

---

Edit: if you need something more advanced, you can register your PropertySources on application startup.

web.xml

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.xxx.core.spring.properties.PropertySourcesApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

file you create:

```
public class PropertySourcesApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertySourcesApplicationContextInitializer.class);

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    LOGGER.info("Adding some additional property sources");
    String[] profiles = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()
    // ... Add property sources according to selected spring profile 
    // (note there already are some property sources registered, system properties etc)
    applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(myPropertySource);
  }

}
```

Once you've done it you just need to add in your context:

```
<context:property-placeholder/>
```

I can't really answer to your question about multiple profiles but I guess you activate them on such an initializer, and you could register the appropriate PropertySource items during profile activations.

Comment: You can access the parsed list of active profiles as an array using `applicationContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()`

Comment: That's right, you can do both. At that time I didn't know we could pass multiple profiles ;)

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of any other way than one you have suggested Emerson, which is to define this bean in a separate `@Configuration` file with an `@Profile` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("override")
@PropertySource("classpath:override.properties")
public class OverriddenConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Bean bean() {
        //if..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you need to support multiple profiles you could do something like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Configuration
    @Profile("default")
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    static class DefaultProperties {
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("!default")
    @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
    static class NonDefaultProperties {
    }
}
```

That way you don't need to define a static configuration class for each profile.
Thanks [David Harkness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167357/425238) for putting me into the right direction.

Comment: fails for multiple active profiles - you're better off just creating separate @Profile settings

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer provides an alternate solution to using properties files with `@PropertySource`. I went this route because it was too cumbersome trying to work with multiple properties files that may each have overrides while avoiding repetitive code.

Create a POJO interface for each related set of properties to define their names and types.

```
public interface DataSourceProperties
{
    String driverClassName();
    String url();
    String user();
    String password();
}
```

Implement to return the default values.

```
public class DefaultDataSourceProperties implements DataSourceProperties
{
     public String driverClassName() { return "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; }
     ...
}
```

Subclass for each profile (e.g. development, production) and override any values that differ from the default. This requires a set of mutually-exclusive profiles, but you can easily add "default" as the alternative to "overrides".

```
@Profile("production")
@Configuration
public class ProductionDataSourceProperties extends DefaultDataSourceProperties
{
     // nothing to override as defaults are for production
}

@Profile("development")
@Configuration
public class DevelopmentDataSourceProperties extends DefaultDataSourceProperties
{
     public String user() { return "dev"; }
     public String password() { return "dev"; }
}
```

Finally, autowire the properties configurations into the other configurations that need them. The advantage here is that you don't repeat any `@Bean` creation code.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BoneCPDataSource source = new BoneCPDataSource();
        source.setJdbcUrl(properties.url());
        ...
        return source;
    }
}
```

I am still not convinced I'll stick with this over manually configuring properties files based on the active profiles in a servlet context initializer. My thought was that doing manual configuration would not be as amenable to unit testing, but I'm not so sure now. I really prefer reading properties files to a list of property accessors.

Comment: The main feature about properties and `@PropertySource` is that you can override it in various ways - for example with environment variables or application switches

Answer (score 1):

All mentioned here solutions are a bit awkward, work only with one profile preset, and they won't work with more/other profiles. Currently a Spring team [refuses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12822) to introduce this feature. But here's the working workaround I've found:

```java
package com.example;

public class MyPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory, SpringApplicationRunListener {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyPropertySourceFactory.class);

    @NonNull private static String[] activeProfiles = new String[0];

    // this constructor is used for PropertySourceFactory
    public MyPropertySourceFactory() {
    }

    // this constructor is used for SpringApplicationRunListener
    public MyPropertySourceFactory(SpringApplication app, String[] params) {
    }

    @Override
    public void environmentPrepared(ConfigurableBootstrapContext bootstrapContext, ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
        activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Loading: {} with profiles: {}", encodedResource.toString(), activeProfiles);
        // here you know all profiles and have the source Resource with main
        // properties, just try to load other resoures in the same path with different 
        // profile names and return them as a CompositePropertySource
    }
}
```

To make it working you have to have `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` with the following content:

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=com.example.MyPropertySourceFactory
```

Now you can put your custom properties file somewhere and load it with `@PropertySources`:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:lib.yml", factory = MyPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class PropertyLoader {
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say 'refuses'. They expressed their standpoint and it makes sense... But still, helpful workaround.