# Any way to split Spring Boot configuration into multiple properties files without having to specify an environment variable/system property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, properties-file

New to Spring Boot here, long-time Spring Framework user though.

I'm looking for a way to split my externalised configuration into multiple `.properties` files, for better readability and manageability.

I already saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862357/1465635): having the ability to specify a list of configuration file names in `spring.config.name` (which, by the way, doesn't seem to be mentioned in Boot reference documentation, correct me if I'm wrong) would solve my problem perfectly, however that configuration property can be specified only via system properties or environment variables. If I try to specify it inside my `application.properties` file, it gets ignored. The same happens for `spring.config.additional-location`. I understand this happens because, when `application.properties` is read, it's too late to tell Spring Boot to search for different externalised configuration file names. However this is not a proper solution, because the way I split my configuration should be an "implementation detail" that the consumer of my application shouldn't be aware of, so I don't expect the consumer to specify an external parameter otherwise my application breaks out-of-the-box.

I think that a way to do this should be provided. Perhaps some import mechanism for `.properties` files or the ability to specify `spring.config.name` even in `application.properties` (some known and reasonable limitations would be acceptable).

The best I could find out is to use `@PropertySource`, but this is not profile aware: unless you use some [ugly nested class hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167357/1465635), or you [put `spring.profiles.active` variable in the resource name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59633656/1465635) (which will break if multiple profiles have been activated), you won't get the benefit you have for `application.properties` profile-specific files.

I was not able to find an "official way" to do this, apart from some statements from [Spring Boot devs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6726#issuecomment-241710618) that say that they're rather promoting the use of a single (possibly giant...) externalised configuration file. It seems like this position is not so popular, judging from the post reactions on GitHub, and IMHO it really seems to be a basic feature missing. I have been working with multiple properties files in Spring Framework (using XML configuration) for years and I never felt that having an only huge file would have been better.

If I understand it right, in Boot 1.x this was in some way possible using the `location` attribute of `@ConfigurationProperties`, which is however missing in Boot 2.x.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Spring Profile?

What you can do is create `application-file1.properties/yml`, `application-file2.properties/yml` and put it in config location and then add `spring.profile.active=<your env profiles>,file1,file2`. 
It will load the files.

This profile entry can be in `bootstrap.yml`, or `JVM args to application`, in `Manifest-<env>.yml` in case of Pivotal Cloud Foundry. Not sure on AWS and other cloud provider.

Hope this will help.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, profiling support is something desirable, but orthogonal to the need of splitting configuration into different `.properties` files. The problem with  `@PropertySource` is indeed that it does not play so well with profiles.