# How to make spring boot test app independent of external property source?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test, spring-test-mvc

I am writing a controller test for a spring boot application. To use the spring application context I am using SpringRunner class. **The problem is the main application class has a property source defined to a specific file path**.

When I am running the test I am getting a FileNotFound exception from the hardcoded file. I want my test to be independent of this property source.

I cannot add the 'ignoreResourceNotFound' option for property source in the main application.

Below is the main application class with property source defined.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("file:/opt/system/conf/smto/management.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ManagementApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ManagementApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am also adding my test class below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application.properties","classpath:management.properties"})
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = {"management-dev"},partitions = 1,
        controlledShutdown = false,brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {
}
```

Comment: Hi & welcome! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12691812/592355) is not really "duplicate", but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167357/592355) is also a solution to your problem. (You'd "decorate" your Tests like `@ActiveProfiles("override")`.)

Comment: Hi & Thanks @xerx593! I tried with the `@ActiveProfiles("override")` but the primary configuration class is still looking for the same file. The changes I made are, moved the test class to the older package (so main app can be found), added `@ActiveProfile("override)` on the test class, and created override.properties. same error

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to create the spring context in this scenario. I have changed my testing class package and because of it, the spring-boot test cannot find the primary configuration class. And then provided all the required packages to create the application context.

Reference for this solution found from spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html).

> Spring Boot’s @*Test annotations will search for your primary configuration automatically whenever you don’t explicitly define one.
>
> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration annotated class. As long as you’ve structured your code in a sensible way your main configuration is usually found.