# Loading XML resource onto java class with JAXB and Spring 4.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, jaxb2

Context:
Java + Spring MVC 4.1 web application.

Input:

1. configuration.xml

`<Configuration>
    <rule>
        <key></key>
        <value></value>
    </rule>
    ...
</Configuration>`

Desired behaviour:
I would like the XML to be parsed onto a java class bean.

What is the best practice?

What I could do is parse the XML manually via JAXB on a BeanFactory but I was hoping there is a more framework based solution (Reading XMLs seems something that is built into Spring...).

**Updated:**

Much like reading a properties file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260652/885902

and I quote:

```
<bean id="myProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:my.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and the bean:

```
@Component
class MyClass {
  @Resource(name="myProperties")
  private Properties myProperties;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    // do whatever you need with properties
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance, help is much appreciated :)

Comment: have a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-objectxml-mapping-example/

Comment: The proposed link has an example of manual XML marshaling/unmarshaling using castor... I was hoping for something with JAXB and built into the framework much like reading a properties file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260652/885902