# How to setProperty in spring-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want to set property in `spring-context.xml` file and instantiate the class which have one setter method of long dataType.

```
package com.mob.test;

class Test
{

private long timeInMillis;

//getter and setter
}
```

## test.properties

```
TIME_IN_MINUTES=10
```

## Spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>    

    <bean id="ready"
        class="com.mob.test.Test">
        <property name="timeInMillis" value="${TIME_IN_MINUTES}*60*1000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

gives NumberFormateException.

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: try <property name="timeInMillis" type="java.lang.Long" value="${TIME_IN_MINUTES}*60*1000"/>

Comment: Value is a String right??I would inject the number in my class , I would String.toInteger(number) and make the calculations inside my class.

Comment: no no value is long

Comment: I mean that you Inject as a String.

Comment: yes we inject it as a string.
Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Check here , do the same and make your calculation inside class. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file   GoodLuck!!  ;)

Comment: Its a textfile you are injecting from after all. So it does not support very complex computations. If you want the computation to be done just add a property timeInMinutes to you class and if timeInMinutes gets set also set timeInMillis in your java code. Looks like better style to me atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:[Expression support for defining bean definitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef)

```
#{ systemProperties['TIME_IN_MINUTES'] * 60 * 1000 }
```

Comment: Thank you Eric Lucia for help.But I read TIME_IN_MINUTES from properties file.

Comment: <property name="timeInMillis" value="#{${'TIME_IN_MINUTES}*60*1000}">