# How to use @value in a target bean of a delegating filter proxy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter, annotations

I have a filter which extends OncePerRequestFilter. I'm trying to read a property value from property file using `@Value`. I'm not getting the actual value from the properties file instead i get the string of the expression used for getting the value.

```
@Value("${project.version}")
private String projectVersion;
```

If i try to use the variable it has `{project.version}` as the value. Am i missing something here ? Any help is appreciated.

My web.xml looks like below

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ModifyRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>modifyRequestFilter</param-value>
  </init-param> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ModifyRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And applicationcontext.xml config for the filter bean is as below

```
<bean id="modifyRequestFilter" class="com.mycompany.filters.ModifyRequestFilter"/>
```

Comment: Where is your properties file located ?

Comment: It is in class path. I'm using it in one of controller and it works fine there

Comment: What is your properties file name?

Comment: This may be a help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file

Comment: Thanks for this link i have all the configs for property placeholder configurer but its still not working.

Comment: Then use property source `@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")`