# Accessing properties with annotation approach in spring mvc 4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties

I am trying to read a simple config.properties file but i keep getting null as the value.

I have config.properties file under the root (at the same level with pom.xml)
I have only one line in config.properties.

```
KEY=baran
```

And i have an AppConfig class like below

```
package tr.com.simroll.ada.rvm.web.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${KEY}")
    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

I am trying to access from my controller like this

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class MovieCategoryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/movieCategory/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String listMovieCategories(ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest req) {


        AppConfig config = new AppConfig();
        System.out.println(config.getTest());

        return "test";
    }
```

Comment: Instantiating a new AppConfig as you do `AppConfig config = new AppConfig();` means it is not a Spring manged bean.

Comment: may be this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260652/2664200

Comment: The examples i have seen on the net doesn`t show how to use it. Could you show me how to access it ?@AlanHay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is that you are creating a new instance of  `AppConfig` in controller, Instead of that you should inject  `AppConfig` which is created by Spring.

Try add the following to your controller

```
@Autowired
AppConfig appConfig;
```

So it becomes..

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class MovieCategoryController {

 @Autowired
 AppConfig appConfig;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/movieCategory/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String listMovieCategories(ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest req) {

        System.out.println(appConfig.getTest());

        return "test";
    }
```