# Spring placeholder (.properties) not found because of an additional slash in the file path

Tags: java, spring

I want to put my application properties file in Tomcat's conf directory therefore I wrote

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${catalina.base}/conf/app.properties"/>
```

I get `FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource`. The app.properties file is there. Problem is an additional slash at the beggining of the path the Spring is looking for the file at. It looks like `/D:/...../conf/app.properties`

**Solution:** Writing ......location="**file:**${catalin..... worked.

Comment: just do `${classpath}/app.properties`, it should be fine :)

Comment: I could but I don't want the file to be in the project's directory.

Comment: Are u sure Catalina base is the right property to use?

Comment: did you look into `@PropertySource("file://your-file")`?? Docs is here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @IndraneelBende What do you mean right?

Comment: @user435421 try `<context:property-placeholder location="file://${catalina.base}/conf/app.properties"/>`

Comment: @YogenRai Typing what you suggested in the file explorer opens the file but on application startup I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: D`

Comment: @user435421 you need to make sure that `catalina.base` is set correctly so that context would be able to read the file.. please have look into the link I've put into answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify as file since you are trying to read from external file as:

`<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.base}/conf/app.properties"/>`

It should be similar to this:
[How to read values from properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file#answer-9260652)

Comment: What do you mean by "need to make sure that catalina.base is set correctly so that context would be able to read the file". I am sure cataline base shows to the right directory because the path in the exception stack trace looks like `/D:/XX/MY_PROJ_NAME/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/app.properties`. When I copy this path from Eclipse's console and remove the first slash the file gets opened in Notepad when I type it in the Windows file explorer. Same happens when I prepend file:// to the `/D:/XX/XX/tmp0/conf/app.properties` and try to access it via file explorer.

Comment: By "same happens" I mean the file gets opened by Notepad but not by application.

Comment: Hmmm... obviously, the second one looks correct! and I am doing the same which is reading properties for and populating the placeholders!!

Comment: @user435421 sounds cool!! Would you please accept the answer and upvote

Comment: If you will add to your answer that `file:` might be the solution besides `file://` then I would do that. For the readers who might miss my updated solution part in the question...

Comment: @user435421  thank you for pointing this out.. :) I didn’t notice that.. you are awesome :)