# Populate spring bean property using annotations only, at run-time

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations, dependencies

I have a bean Parent with just one property attr.

```
class Parent
{
   String attr;
   public void doStuff(){
      //stuff
   }
   public String getAttr() {
       return attr;
   }
   public void setAttr(String attr) {
       this.attr=attr;
   }
}
```

I have three beans that extend this Parent bean.
My spring.xml looks like this-

```
<bean id="parent" class="Parent"/>

<bean id="child1" parent="parent">
    <property name="attr" value="Sample value 1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="child2" parent="parent">
    <property name="attr" value="Sample value 2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="child3" parent="parent">
    <property name="attr" value="Sample value 3"/>
</bean>
```

I want to do the same thing using annotations.
Problem is that I have to do this storefront and all the beans in my controller are declared as -

```
@Resource
@Qualifier("child1")
Parent child1;
```

Is there a way I can add the property to the child beans using annotations or any other approach in controller i.e. without using spring.xml?

Is there a way of doing this using the @Value annotation. Problem is that I don't have a static value that comes from a property file. I have 3 different value for  3 different beans.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t this work, if you have three different values in your properties file

[see post here](http://filehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-)

`@Value(“${child1.attr}”) 
@Value(“${child2.attr}”)
@Value(“${child3.attr}”)`

Comment: is that even possible? I think this is syntactically incorrect. Also, I don't have a property file.

Comment: The @Value will work so long as you have a properties from-properties-file