# How to define a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer local to a specific bean?

Tags: spring

I've been using `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and in my experience ("citation needed" LOL) it sets the property values globally.

Is there a way to specify different `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instances for different beans within the same application context xml?

My current code is similar to

```
<bean id="a" class="X">
  <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <property name="many" value="more"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="X">
  <property name="foo" value="baz"/>
  <property name="number_of_properties" value="a zillion"/>
</bean>
```

I would like to do something like (pseudo-code below):

```
<bean id="a" class="X">
  ... parse the contents of "a.properties" here ...
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="X">
  ... parse the contents of "b.properties" here ...
</bean>
```

The above is non-working pseudo code to illustrate the concept; the point being, I want a different properties file to feed each bean.

**WHY?**

I want to have those specific properties in separate properties file and not in XML.

Comment: Use prototype scope for your custom configurer. Each bean will get its own instance

Comment: I need a different instance of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with different properties. I don't think prototype scope does that.

Comment: Why do you need that? Why not simply have a single one with multiple property files? What is yoiur usecase?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a single one with multiple property files"? How could one instance have different values?

Comment: Please see clarification edits.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following link can br helpful to you.
[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file)

where  @Value("${my.property.name}") annotation is used to bind the property file to a variable of type Properties which will reside in your bean class where you intend to use that properties file.

and you can define multiplte proprtiesplaceholder as below:

```
<bean id="myProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:my.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and use the id as reference in your bean variable to initialize properties file to the bean.

And it will be handy to include   with placeholder bean.

Kindly refer [Importance of Unresolvable Placeholder](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-be-careful-when-using-propertyplaceholderconfigurer) link for detailed info regarding its usage.

Hope this was helpful.